# Does anyone know of an agnostic .NET SQL json parser driver?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, json, oracle

I have a challenge at my current job that I'm hoping someone will be able to help me with.

Basically, we have some use cases that require us to store unstructured data in a database, but also be able to perform queries against it.

The thing is, every other use case we have requires us to use a structured language so our core platform has been heavily developed over SQL (where we support SQL Server, Oracle and other SQL servers - and, historically, have managed to stay SQL DB agnostic by not using any database specific features like stored procedures or anything like that and sticking to standard SQL).

Anyway, we now have the need to store and query unstructured data so two things jumped to mind:
- use a NoSQL database
- or use a SQL database with json parsing capabilities like PostgreSQL, SQL Server or Oracle Server

The thing is, we can't force our customers to install yet another database, and I don't also want to limit the number of different SQL compatible database services our customers have been using for several years now.

Having said all this, here's my actual question:
- does anyone know of an agnostic .NET SQL json parser driver that can allow me to transparently store JSON on different SQL services, but then give me an agnostic querying / parsing interface that I can use without having to worry about the underlying server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article that describes how to store EF objects as JSON https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1166099/Entity-Framework-Storing-complex-properties-as-JSO

Are stored procedures valid option for you? In theory you might create stored procedures that have SQL code with JSON functions that search JSON columns and then just call them from .Net code. There would be different implementations of stored procedures for every database, but your .Net call will just call them. Hopefully in the future EF will support LINQ translation to SQL when you query JSON fields.

If you are using SQL Server and Oracle you might even execute the raw SQL queries from .Net code, because both support JSON_VALUE function.

Comment: That information is great BUT not exactly what I was looking for.
Basically, I need to be able to store arbitrary JSON payloads and then query them: e.g. select all records where json_column.json_property['x'] > 5.

I want to push that querying logic to the server side so the processing is done server side (for performance reasons)!

Different databases allow for this capability, but using different constructs / query languages (given this is not really a standard SQL feature). So what I'm looking for is a driver or component that gives me JSON query capabilities in an agnostic way.

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately JSON support is new in databases so I'm not aware of that kind of framework. However, if you are targeting SQL Server and Oracle they have aligned functionalities so you can store in both database JSON as text and query it with identical query, e.g.: SELECT * FROM dbo.collection WHERE JSON_VALUE(Jsoncolumn, '$.property') = 'Test'